# Set Matplotlib backend when using Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Matplotlib backend keeps reverting to `TkAgg`. This is a problem because in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), you can't do GUI stuff, and so I get the error

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I've tried adding a `matplotlibrc` file to `/home/<user>/.config/matplotlib` (in the Windows filesystem, this is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<user>\.config\matplotlib`).

My `matplotlibrc` looks like this

```
backend : Agg
```

However, if I do this

```
$ cd /home/<user>/.config/matplotlib
$ ls -A
```

nothing shows up.

When I try

```
 $ python
 >>> import matplotlib
 >>> matplotlib.get_backend()
 'TkAgg'
```

so clearly it's not setting the backend to `Agg`. Why not?

**Update:**

I've figured out that putting `backend : Agg` in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<user>\.config\matplotlib\matplotlibrc` changes the backend in Windows Python only, leaving Linux Python as `TkAgg`. Which is odd, because Windows Python should only be using `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I had created the matplotlibrc file using Windows - this is why it didn't show up when I tried `$ ls -A` in bash. So I did this instead (after deleting the Windows-created file):

```
$ cd /home/<user>/.config/matplotlib
$ touch matplotlibrc
$ echo "backend : Agg" > matplotlibrc
```

(`touch matplotlibrc` creates an empty matplotlibrc file)

This did the trick, and my Windows python matplotlib's backend was left as Qt4Agg.

---

Here it is on one line for copy/paste:

```
cd /home/<user>/.config/matplotlib; touch matplotlibrc && echo "backend : Agg" > matplotlibrc
```

Comment: Indeed [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: if we're running the code on ubuntu for windows, how can we get a plot to "show up".  Maybe decorate .show() to just savefig as png in a windows folder and have some tool monitoring the folder and showing images? better way?